# remove transparency of background Image

Tags: image-processing

I have the following image:

[image]

As you can see the background is kind of white-ish.
Now my question is: How can I remove this transperancy of the background image ?

Comment: What do you mean by "transparency"? The image seems to have no alpha channel...

Comment: @J.M. I would like to make the image background as "sharp" as the foreground. Basically I mean by "transparency" the fact that the background looks like one took the original slide and increased the transparency, then placed the speaker in front.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a pixel is part of the transparent slide on white color all channels will have a high value. The code below checks which pixels have a channel whose value is less than `tol` and extents the set with some `radius`. The complement set to the found pixels are assumed to be the background.

```
tol = 0.6;
radius = 1;

(*background pixel positions*)
pos = Complement[Tuples[Range /@ ImageDimensions[im][[{2, 1}]]],
   Union @@ Outer[Plus, Tuples[Range[-radius, radius], 2], Position[
      Clip[Map[Min, ImageData[im], {2}], {tol, tol}, {0, 1}], 0.], 1]];
```

The smallest channel value indicates how transparent the background is.

```
r = Min@Extract[ImageData[im], pos];
```

Cancel transparency:

```
Image[MapAt[(# - {r, r, r})/(1 - r) &, ImageData[im], pos]]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer  ! Thanks a lot ! :)